# How to create an Event with "e" variable members?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, events, event-handling

I've created an Event to manage the execution end of a process

```
' <summary>
' Event raised when CoreConverter process has exited.
' </summary>
Public Shared Event Exited As EventHandler(Of ExitedEventArgs)
Public Class ExitedEventArgs : Inherits EventArgs
    Public Property Message As String
End Class
```

The event is raised when the process exits, to send a message which can contain information message or error message.

When the process exits, I return only one message, for example if erroroutput is empty then I send the StandardOutput, but if the ErrorOutput is not empty then I only send the ErrorOutput.

```
    Select Case CoreConverter.ExitCode

        Case 0
             RaiseEvent Exited(StandardOutput, Nothing) ' Return StandardOutput

        Case Else
             RaiseEvent Exited(ErrorOutput, Nothing) ' Return ErrorOutput

    End Select
```

What I want to do is to do this more professional to be able to manage both message type in the "e" variable (I think this is the right way to do this, if I'm wrong just tell me please)

```
Private sub ProcessExited(byval Message as string, byval e as eventargs) _
handles myClass.Exited

    ' here I want to be able to manage both message types like this:

    msgbox(e.ErrorOutput)
    msgbox(e.StandardOutput)

end sub
```

Really I want to do this also to add more information which could be accesed trough the "e" variable like I've seen in other third party Classes, for example:

```
msgbox(e.ProcessHandle)
msgbox(e.ToalExecutionTime)
msgbox(e.SomeExtraInfo)
```

I've searched in MSDN how I could make custom "e" members but I can't find anything, so I don't know how to start doing this.

Comment: I don't get your question. You already have one "custom" member. Why not add a second and third?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're so close, you just need to add more properties to the class you are passing as "e".

```
Public Class ExitedEventArgs : Inherits EventArgs
    Public Property ErrorOutput As String
    Public Property StandardOutput As String
    Public Property SomeExtraInfo as String
End Class
```

When you define the event, do this: (never seen it being declared like a generic???)

```
Public Shared Event Exited As EventHandler(byval sender as object,byval e as ExitedEventArgs)
```

This allows you to pass over WHAT is calling the event, very useful sometimes, and and instance of YOUR event args (notice the "as ExitedEventArgs").

Then when you call it, you might do something like this:

```
Dim x as new ExitedEventArgs
x.ErrorOutput = "Your Error"
x.StandardOutput = "Some Output text"
x.SomeExtraInfo = "You extra info here"
RaiseEvent Exited(me,x)
```

Comment: Your example helped me a lot, really thankyou for your time. only I have a question, when using the "New" constructor of the "ExitedEventArgs" it will release the memory automatically or I need to dispose it manually?, I don't want to work more variables so this is what I've did: RaiseEvent Exited(Nothing, New ExitedEventArgs With {.ErrorOutput = ErrorOutput, etc...}) , but I'm not sure if that "new" will increase the memory when I raise the event again and again and so...

Comment: Another question is about the sender variable, which is the correct value to pass? I remember you that I'm writing this code in a Class, so I can't send a "Me" neither "Mybase" like you wrote in your example, you can see that I'm pass "Nothing" as a "sender" in my comment but I dont knnow if that's much correct.

Comment: If you are passing normal variables, they will be released when there are no more pointers. If usings something more complex, you can implements IDispoable to unsure they are cleaned up but you shouldn't have to. As far as sender, you would pass ME, if it were an instance of a class you are calling the RaiseEvents from. If it is shared and will always be shared, dont include the sender variable in the raiseevent, because you will never use it and it just adds confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own event arg classes as simply as this:

```
Friend Class MyEventArgs
    Public Property Foo As String
    Public Property Bar As Integer

    Sub new(t1 as String, r2 As Integer)
        Foo = t1
        Bar = t2
    End Sub

End Class

Public Event MyEvent(ByVal ea As MyEventArgs)
```

Raise an event:

```
Protected Friend Sub MakeEvent(ByVal ea As MyEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent MyEvent(ea)
End Sub
```

It works fine, **however** if you run Code Analysis on that, it will tell you that it should inherit from EventArgs.  So, do it, but you can still append your own properties:

```
Friend Class MyEventArgs
    Inherits From EventArgs

    Public Property Foo As String
```

There isnt much of value in EventArgs, but it makes CA happy.